Add-Migration error what is wrong for version 8
the add- migration firstmigration cannot run
to run the command because this is part of an assignment and this assignment is very important because i failed the first one just because of this problem and all the help is needed this is my last chance to pass this assignment thank you .

Hi and welcome to SO. Please [edit] the question, you need to provide a lot more details like how is your DB configured? What does your model look like? What error are you getting?

Could you please share a bit more details what you are tryig to achieve? What command did you executed and what is the error you got?

Hello have you tried the solution provided? Did you able to made any progress on this?


Add-Migration error what is wrong for version 8

In order to execute initial migration command, we need few prerequisite. You should ensure that the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools package is installed within your project. See the below screenshot:

If it's not, then you could add it from NuGet package manager or or simply writing command in the Package Manager Console:
For Package Manager Library:

For Package Manager Console Command:
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools -Version 8.0.4
You should have like below:

Note: In addition, please double check you have correct DbContext and connection string pointing to your desired database which has been added within your program.cs file. Please refer to this official document if you need more example.
